# How to get generic method on closed generic type, having open MethodInfo from open generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Imagine type like this (C#):

```
public interface IAmGeneric<T>
{
   void SoAmI<T1>(T one, T1 two);
}
```

Given I have open generic `MethodInfo` from open generic version of the type (`IAmGeneric<>.SoAmI<>()`) and the following array

```
new[] { typeof(int), typeof(string) }'
```

I'm looking for well performing and reliable way of getting closed version of the `MethodInfo` like this:

```
IAmGeneric<int>.SoAmI<string>()
```

UPDATE:

by reliable I mean it should handle cases when the method is not public, has dozen overloads, uses generic arguments from base type, not just its immediate interface etc.

Comment: If you already have a `MethodInfo` from the interface, why do you care about overloads and generic arguments from base type? The solution from @DarrenKopp is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Something like so? Not sure exactly what you are looking for, maybe expand on your question... This definitely would need some checks added (like checking if declaring type is generic / if method is generic, etc)

```
var method = typeof(IAmGeneric<>).GetMethod("SoAmI");
var types = new[] { typeof(int), typeof(string) };


var methodTypeParams = method.GetGenericArguments();
var fullType = method.DeclaringType.MakeGenericType(types.Take(types.Length - methodTypeParams.Length).ToArray());
var fullMethod = fullType.GetMethod(method.Name).MakeGenericMethod(types.Skip(types.Length - methodTypeParams.Length).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a case that is pretty complex to get right:

```
public interface IAmGeneric<T>
{
    void SoAmI<T1, T2>(T one, T1 two, T2 three);
    void SoAmI<T1, T2>(T one, T2 two, T1 three);
    void SoAmI<T1, T2>(T1 one, T two, T2 three);
    void SoAmI<T1, T2>(T2 one, T1 two, T three);
    void SoAmI<T1, T2, T3>(T2 one, T1 two, T3 three);
}
```

For me the solution is to use `GetMethods(...).Select()` and compare method name, parameter count, types and type parameters count to find the right method (basically everything that is part of the signature of the method).

Comment: yeap, that might work, and that's what I'm doing right now. However the performance is far from stellar, hence I'm asking if there's a better way

Answer (score 0):

Use [`MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145377.aspx), as pointed out in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4103366/82959):

```
var ty = typeof(IAmGeneric<>);
var numTyParams = ty.GenericTypeArguments.Length;
var mi = ... do something with ty to get generic def for SoAmI<> ...
var parameters = new[] { typeof(int), typeof(string) };
var output = MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(mi.MethodHandle, ty.MakeGenericType(parameters.Take(numTyParams).ToArray()).TypeHandle).MakeGenericMethod(parameters.Skip(numTyParams).ToArray());
```