# How to get MethodInfo for open generic type from MethodInfo of closed type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Assume I have a class like so:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public void Foo(T t)
    {
    }
}
```

Now, assume, I have an instance of `MyClass<int>` and a `MethodInfo` of its `Foo` method.
Calling `methodInfo.GetParameters()` will return a `ParameterInfo` array with one entry, referring to type `int`. My problem is, that I can't seem to find out, if that parameter was declared as `int` in the class or as `T`.

**What am I trying to achieve?**
At runtime, I want to read the documentation of the method specified by `MethodInfo` from the XML Doc file generated by Visual Studio.
For the above defined method, the key looks like this:

```
<namespace>.MyClass`1.Foo(`0)
```

The `` `0 `` refers to the first generic type parameter of the declaring class. To be able to construct this string, I need to somehow get this information.
*But how?* `MethodInfo` doesn't seem to contain that info...

Comment: Advanced reflection techniques usually requires falling back to IMetaDataImport2.  Not that easy to use from C#.

Comment: @HansPassant: Would this interface support my scenario?

Comment: So if your method was "public void Foo(int i, T t, string s)", you would want to get something like "<namespace>.MyClass`1.Foo(int, `0, string)"?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4103366/82959 for the easy way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key seems to be [`Type.ContainsGenericParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.containsgenericparameters.aspx) on the parameter type:

Given

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public void Foo(T t)
    {
    }

    public void Bar(int i)
    {

    }
}
```

Then

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new MyClass<int>();

        // Closed type
        var closedType = obj.GetType();

        // Open generic (typeof(MyClass<>))
        var openType = closedType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

        // Methods on open type
        var fooT = openType.GetMethod("Foo");
        var barint = openType.GetMethod("Bar");

        // Parameter types
        var tInFoo = fooT.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
        var iInBar = barint.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;

        // Are they generic?
        var tInFooIsGeneric = tInFoo.ContainsGenericParameters;
        var iInBarIsGeneric = iInBar.ContainsGenericParameters;

        Console.WriteLine(tInFooIsGeneric);
        Console.WriteLine(iInBarIsGeneric);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

outputs

```
True
False
```

This will obviously need more work for overloads and so on.

Comment: Aha! That looks pretty good. Will check it later in detail. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to accept your answer. It was spot on.

Comment: How can I get the correct `MethodInfo` if I have overloads of the `Foo` method? `GetMethod` throws an `AmbiguousMatchException`. `GetMethod` needs to receive the parameters type but I can't find the generic parameter from the `MethodInfo` closed type

Comment: @AlexandrePepin then use [`Type.GetMethods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td205ybf.aspx) with a `Where(mi => mi.Name="Whatever")`, then further filters to pick the one you want. [Ask your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you need more after you've tried this...

Answer (score 2):

This was a tricky one. If you have a `MethodInfo` instance of a (***non-***generic) method, which was obtained on an ***open generic*** `Type`, you *can* actually use it to repeatedly close the method (i.e., with different generic arguments for the *enclosing* type).

The key is to use the obscure static function [`MethodInfo.GetMethodFromHandle(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodfromhandle):

**Complete working example:**

```cs
static class MyType<T>
{
    public static int TheMethod() => typeof(T).MetadataToken;  // demo method
};
```

**How to use:**

```cs
static void demo()
{
    var Topen = typeof(MyType<>);
    var mi_open = Topen.GetMethod("TheMethod");  // can't Invoke() this one...

    // ...later perhaps...  MyType<ushort>.TheMethod()

    var Tclose = Topen.MakeGenericType(typeof(ushort));
    var mi = MethodInfo.GetMethodFromHandle(mi_open.MethodHandle, Tclose.TypeHandle);
    var ret = (int)mi.Invoke(null, null);        // works --> 0x02000150

    // later yet... MyType<Guid>.TheMethod(), reusing 'mi_open' (and Topen)...

    Tclose = Topen.MakeGenericType(typeof(Guid));
    mi = MethodInfo.GetMethodFromHandle(mi_open.MethodHandle, Tclose.TypeHandle);
    ret = (int)mi.Invoke(null, null);            // works --> 0x020000eb
}
```

Notice that the `Tclose` type handle (passed in as the second arg) is *not* simply the handle of the type argument `T` that you ultimately want to parametrize with. Rather, you have to use that `T` to close the original `Topen` (open) generic type first, and then use the handle for the resulting (closed) generic type.

In other words, you can't close a *method* without first explicitly closing its generic *type*.

Comment: I don't know why this hasn't got more upvotes!

Answer (score 1):

Could you get the definition of the generic class through [Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx) and find there the definition for the same method, say, by name (and the signature), and then compare `Foo(T t)` and `Foo(int t)`:

```
MyClass<int> c = new MyClass<int>();

Type concreteType = c.GetType();
Console.Write("Concrete type name:");
Console.WriteLine(concreteType.FullName);
Console.WriteLine();

MethodInfo concreteMethod = concreteType.GetMethod("Foo");
if (concreteMethod != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(concreteMethod.Name);
    foreach (ParameterInfo pinfo in concreteMethod.GetParameters())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pinfo.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(pinfo.ParameterType);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

if (concreteType.IsGenericType)
{
    Console.Write("Generic type name:");
    Type genericType = concreteType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    Console.WriteLine(genericType.FullName);
    Console.WriteLine();

    MethodInfo genericMethod = genericType.GetMethod("Foo");
    if (genericMethod != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(genericMethod.Name);
        foreach (ParameterInfo pinfo in genericMethod.GetParameters())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pinfo.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(pinfo.ParameterType);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about that too, but I am not really sure how that would work out with overloaded methods.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, agree that could be a tricky thing to find correspondent methods' overloads. Yet I don't see the other way out either.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have considered using Mono.Cecil instead of .Net's reflection.

```
// Gets the AssemblyDefinition (similar to .Net's Assembly).
Type testType = typeof(MyClass<>);
AssemblyDefinition assemblyDef = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(new Uri(testType.Assembly.CodeBase).LocalPath);
// Gets the TypeDefinition (similar to .Net's Type).
TypeDefinition classDef = assemblyDef.MainModule.Types.Single(typeDef => typeDef.Name == testType.Name);
// Gets the MethodDefinition (similar to .Net's MethodInfo).
MethodDefinition myMethodDef = classDef.Methods.Single(methDef => methDef.Name == "Foo");
```

then `myMethodDef.FullName` returns

```
"System.Void MyNamespace.MyClass`1::Foo(System.Int32,T,System.String)"
```

and `classDef.GenericParameters[0].FullName` returns

```
"T"
```

Note that Mono.Cecil uses a different way of writing generics, nested classes and arrays:

```
List[T] => List<T>
MyClass+MyNestedClass => MyClass/MyNestedClass
int[,] => int[0...,0...]
```

Comment: The problem is that I already have a MethodInfo object for which I need to retrieve that info.