# Get Generic Constructor From Closed Version (Net Standard 1.1)

Tags: c#, generics, .net-standard

I'll start by linking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102940/if-i-have-a-methodinfo-on-a-closed-generic-type-is-there-an-easy-way-to-switch-t/4103366#4103366) which shows one way to do what I want to do - unfortunately it's not possible in .Net Standard 1.1.

Although I need this to work for *any* generic type, here's an example type:

```
class MyGeneric<T>
{
   public MyGeneric(T a1, string a2) { }
   public MyGeneric(T a1, double a2) { }
}
```

I want a function which, when supplied with a `ConstructorInfo` for a *concrete* `MyGeneric<>`, for example:

- `MyGeneric<int>..ctor(int, double)`

Will return another `ConstructorInfo` for the same constructor, but for the unbound generic type `MyGeneric<>` instead:

- `MyGeneric<T>..ctor(T, double)`

> The purpose is then to be able to go the other way - i.e. given `MyGeneric<T>..ctor(T, double)`, I can get the same constructor for *any* bound/closed version of that generic - e.g. `MyGeneric<DateTime>..ctor(DateTime, double)`, or `MyGeneric<Foo>..ctor(Foo, double)`.
>
> It must also work when the generic type parameters appear as type arguments to another generic in the constructor signature - e.g. `MyGeneric(IEnumerable<T>)`

The best implementation I can find is the one from the link above, which uses [`MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(RuntimeMethodHandle, RuntimeTypeHandle)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodfromhandle?view=netstandard-1.1#System_Reflection_MethodBase_GetMethodFromHandle_System_RuntimeMethodHandle_System_RuntimeTypeHandle_):

```
return (ConstructorInfo)MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(
           ctor.MethodHandle, 
           ctor.DeclaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().TypeHandle);
```

*(assumes `ctor` contains a reference to the concrete generic type's version of the constructor)*

This works for *all* constructors on *all* types, regardless of how wacky the relationship between the generic type's own type parameters and the types of the constructor parameters.

However, whilst .netstandard1.1 *does* have the `MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle` static method, there doesn't appear to be a way to get the `RuntimeMethodHandle` from a `MethodInfo` object (i.e. no `MethodHandle` property on the `MethodBase` base class of `Constructorinfo`).

So it looks to me like it's impossible to do it like this.

### Current implementation for .Net Standard 1.1

Currently, my implementation for .Net Standard 1.1 assumes that the order of members returned by the `Type` (or `TypeInfo`) for an open generic will be the same as those returned for any closed generic built from it:

```
var position = Array.IndexOf(
    TypeHelpers.GetConstructors(ctor.DeclaringType),
    ctor);
if(position >= 0)
{
    return TypeHelpers.GetConstructors(
        ctor.DeclaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())[position];
}
```

***Note**: The `TypeHelpers.GetConstructors` method just returns public constructors for a type using either the old or newer reflection APIs depending on target framework*

Once I know the index, I then reuse it to map back from the open generic's constructor to the closed one for any closed/bound generic built from that open generic.

This does appear to work (***with caveats, see next***), which *kinda* makes sense (since all concrete generics should logically 'inherit' all the field/method metadata lists in the same order) - but it feels wrong, because we should *never* rely on the order of the results returned from any of the reflection APIs.

***Caveats*** 
The above `TypeInfo`-based solution works *intermittently* because it relies on `ConstructorInfo` being cached whenever the `DeclaredConstructors` API is used, so that you can compare reference equality for the constructors.  But it turns out that this isn't always the case!

### A better way?

Is there a better way?  Is it possible to get `RuntimeMethodHandle` or `RuntimeTypeHandle` from a `ConstructorInfo` in .NetStandard 1.1 - or should I be consigned to searching arrays of methods/constructors as in the second code example?

It seems odd that .NetStandard 1.1 has the `MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle` overloads, but doesn't seem to provide any way to get the handles that you need as parameters!

Answer (score 0):

I am still on a learning curve for reflection in core but Take a look a the following example and see if it can help.

```
//assumes ctor contains a reference to the 
//concrete generic type's version of the constructor
public Type GetDeclaringType(ConstructorInfo ctor) {
    var type = ctor.DeclaringType;//Gets the class that declares this member.
    var typeInfo = type.GetTypeInfo();//Returns TypeInfo representation of specified type.
    if (typeInfo.IsGenericType) {
        type = typeInfo.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    }
    return type;
}
```

So assuming ctor is `MyGeneric<DateTime>..ctor(DateTime, double)`

```
var declaredType = GetDeclaringType(ctor); //MyGeneric<>
var closedType = declaredType.MakeGenericType(typeof(int));//MyGeneric<int>
//constructors
var typeInfo = closedType.GetTypeInfo();
var constructors = typeInfo.GetConstructors();
//MyGeneric<int>..ctor(int, double)
var constructorWithDouble = constructors
    .Where(ctor => ctor.GetParameters().Skip(1).First().ParameterType == typeof(double))
    .First();
```

Comment: While this works for a known type; I need to be far more general, unfortunately: I need to get the `ConstructorInfo` on the generic type definition so I can then apply it to *any* closed version of that generic - so I need something that works without any prior knowledge of the types I might be working with.